# Hypotheses about neural coding and neural correlates of concepts and reasoning - at the level of neurons and synapses

Tags: neural-network, theory-of-mind, thought

Are there some hypotheses about neural coding of language, concepts and logical reasoning in the brain, about neural correlates of thoughts? When I search the books, then I find lot of books about neural coding, but they are mostly about representation of stimuli and generation of action and not about thought processes.

I am interested in the emergence of mind in the brain-like neural networks. I guess, that the final answer is not yet given (and maybe never will), but there should be some hypothesis and my question is about those hypotheses.

I am interested in the microscopic theories only, only the level of neurons and synapses. I am aware of the research, that uses fMRI and similar technologies, but they are exploring only mesoscopic lever. GEVI (genetically engineered voltage indicators) are promising tools for microscopic exploration and there are efforts to use them. So - there should be also hypotheses at the microscopic level about emergence of mind.

Comment: GEVIs will likely never be used in live humans. I suppose one could study the primitive language of primates, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: I know of some research in primates that was able to prove that midbrain neurons [literally encode](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/37/15462.full.pdf) a time discounting function.

Comment: There's probably too much good material out there for any one answer to do this justice! But you might enjoy this https://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/index.html and there's an associated edx course that walks through the material. I guess the crux is what you consider 'mind'. This treatment heads towards memory and decision making stuff, which is definitely part of 'mind', but other interesting parts might be distinct (like language for example).

Comment: Many thanks, fantastic suggestion. I searched for "neural code", but "neuronal dynamics" brings lot of interesting stuff as well. I am starting to read this book. But still - aren't there hypothesis, that maps Conceptual Knowledge Graph into synaptic weights or rates (without embeddings into vector spaces so beloved into computer science) and that encodes reasoning over this encoded Knowledge Graphs (without the traditional artificial encoding of first order logic into neural networks a la https://d-nb.info/1008183652/34). At least one hypothesis from biology about concepts and reasoning?